# How to calculate the variance of dataframe in this format?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here I have a simplified dataframe (The real one is in the same format but just amplified)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

row = (1, 2)
columns = ["x", "y", "x", "y", "x", "y", "x", "y"]
data = ([10, 2, 8, 1.5, 9, 2, 11, 1.6], [8, 3, 7.5, 2.2, 9, 2, 8.6, 2.3])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = row, columns = columns)
```

[image]

I want to calculate the variance of x, y for both of 1, 2, and the ideal format is

[image]

Any hint or help is appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this -

1. Unstack to get the x, y columns as indexes
2. groupby over both the levels [x,y] and [1,2] and calculate variance.
3. Unstack and transpose to get [x,y] as columns.

```
df.unstack().groupby(level=[0,1]).var().unstack().T
```

```
          x         y
1  1.666667  0.069167
2  0.435833  0.189167
```

Comment: thanks first. May I ask what does your "level = [0, 1]" imply?

Comment: so you already have 1,2 as an index. When you use `unstack` you get [x,y] columns become indexes too. therefore to group over the multi index array you mentioned that you want the grouby on levels 0 which is x,y and levels 1 which is 1,2

Comment: print `df.unstack()` separately and it will become clear as to what levels i am referring to.